# Как в cmake сделать сборку двух проектов?

Tags: c++, cmake

Есть клиент-серверная игра. В ней есть папки src/server и src/client. Внутри есть файлы с main функциями. Как настроить cmake чтобы он их собрал и запустил?

Comment: С эти папки уже содержат CMakeLists.txt файлы?

Comment: Нет, не содержат

Comment: тогда для начала хорошо бы их написать. А потом просто один батник/sh файл и готово. Писать универсальный cmake файл сложно, поэтому ничего пока написать  не могу.

Comment: никаких "универсальных" cmake фалов не нужно... тем более батников и прочих скриптов!

Answer (score 0):

Добавить всем проектам `CMakeLists.txt`. Добавить "корневой" `src/CMakeLists.txt` (или по хорошему уровнем выше, ибо, судя по всему `src/` это не корень репозитория, или где там оно...), который будет делать

```
...
add_subdirectory(client)
add_subdirectory(server)
...
```

В зависимости от предпочтений и дальнейших желаний (например может нужно пакеты какие-то сделать в конечном итоге) и/или вкусовых предпочтений:

- можно собирать все в рамках одного "проекта" -- тогда "корневой" `CMakeLists.txt` будет иметь единственный (на все CMake файлы) вызов `project(BlahBlah...)`;
- можно сделать по проекту на клиента и сервера -- тогда вызов `project(BlahBlahClient...)` помещаем в `src/client/CMakeLists.txt` и аналогично поступаем с сервером.